# Derivation of covariant derivative by means of parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, topology, covariance

I've studied covariant derivative in many courses so far, but I got stuck on the definition given by the teacher notes of the exam of Topological QFT.

[image]

[image]

1. I think that he improperly used the name "infinitesimal holonomy" since holonomy is defined on a closed path, and I think $h_{x,x+dx}$ is rather an infinitesimal operation for parallel transport. Is it right?
2. It seems to me that $h_{x,x+dx}$ transports a vector from $x$ to $x+dx$, but the way he define the transported vector $\tilde{\psi}(x+dx)=h^{-1}_{x+dx,x}\psi(x+dx) (=h_{x,x+dx}\psi(x+dx))$ makes me think that it does the opposite operation (also because we want the vector to be transported in the same point of $\psi(x)$). Maybe I didn't fully understand the meaning of $h_{x,x+dx}$?
3. I don't understand the expression in (3.14). If I replace (3.13) in LHS of (3.14) I get again $lim_{dx\rightarrow 0}\frac{\psi(x+dx)-\psi(x)}{dx}$ (plus the term with the connection), but I think this is again bad defined so I cannot take the limit in order to obtain $\partial_{\mu}\psi$.

Thank you for help.

**EDIT**

Regard the second question, I just realized that he defined the holonomy in a closed path as

$\psi'=H_{\gamma}^{-1}\psi$

Where $\psi'$ is the final vector. So perhaps is just a matter of definition.

Comment: Let me refer you to this excelent playlist of video lectures [by Professor Frederic P. Schuller](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&si=7frIs2zkQrYosL9F). You can start on lecture 19. The general notion is that the covariant derivative is defined by a choice of a connection on the principal bundle, and the derivative described in the pages you linked is what you get when you push it all down to the base manifold, I am not sure what is meant by that definition of infinitesimal holonomy, but hopefully with the videos' help you can make better sense of it

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a deeper approach than the one of my professor so it didn't solve my doubts (that maybe come from some abuse of notation of my teacher), but they were very interesting and clear lectures